# Send custom object with reference and update values in both object: iOS

Tags: ios, swift, tableview, swift5

I need to update values in the reference class to my custom cell.

I want to archive :

1. Get data from API // Completed
2. create custom object(model) from API // Completed
3. Send object reference to custom cell from array
4. change value in custom cell
5. Update value in view controller's array

I read this link but can't update values

https://medium.com/@abhimuralidharan/difference-between-value-type-and-a-reference-type-in-ios-swift-18cb5145ad7a

https://developer.apple.com/swift/blog/?id=10

Below is my class

```
class Post {
    // https://www.raywenderlich.com/9481-reference-vs-value-types-in-swift
    var objPost:ObjPost

    init(_ objPost:ObjPost) {
        self.objPost = objPost
    }
}

struct ObjPost:Codable {
    var id:Int
    var contentAvailable : Bool
    var userId : Int
    var userName : String
    var userProfileImage: String
    var subTitle : String
    var postedSince : String
    var isPin : Bool
    var location : String
    var lat : String
    var long: String
    var isLiked: Bool
    var isDisliked : Bool
    var likes : Int
    var dislikes: Int
    var shares: Int
    var comments:Int
    var description: String
    var albumId: Int
    var privacy: Int
    var isEditable: Bool
    var media:[ObjMedia]
}

struct ObjMedia:Codable {
    var id: Int
    var type: Int // 1 = Image, 2=Video
    var url: String
    var description: String?
    var thumb: String
    var isLiked: Bool
    var isDisliked:Bool
    var likes:Int
    var dislikes: Int
    var shares: Int
    var comments: Int
    var isEditable:Bool
    var isPin: Bool
    var isCoverMedia: Bool
}
```

**Pass Reference** of Object **ObjPost** `tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath`

> In below code get reference object from array with **-1** value **indexPath.row-1**, Because 1st row is fix UI in my project requirement.

`cell.objPostDetails = Post(arrPosts[indexPath.row-1].objPost)`

#### Custom Cell Code and

```
var objPostDetails:Post! // Create object variable.
```

#### Update values code in custom cell

```
self.objPostDetails.objPost.isLiked  = !self.actionSelected // Here is action selected is bool variable
self.objPostDetails.objPost.isDisliked  = self.actionSelected // Here is action selected is bool variable
```

My Problem is update value in the cell but not update values in the array
When I scroll up and down then old values is visible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Also, take `ObjPost` and `ObjMedia` as a `class` instead of `struct`. Then everything worked as expected.

```
class ObjPost:Codable {
    var id:Int
    var contentAvailable : Bool
    var userId : Int
    var isDisliked : Bool
 ...
}

class ObjMedia:Codable {
    var id: Int
    var type: Int
    var url: String
    var description: String?
...
}
```

Comment: Should I create another object `class Post` for get reference  ?

Comment: There is no need to create post class. You can do it by using the existing ObjPost and ObjMedia class. Thanks